# Разные пути в С++, какой путь выбрать ?

Tags: c++

В данный момент устроиться на позицию Junior Developer очень тяжело, а если выбор среды обитания С++ то это практически невозможно ибо нужен опыт или очень хорошие знания. Но также проблема прокачать skills состоит в том что направлений несколько и даже больше, если (допустим) на Java это мир Android и Enterprise то есть их по сути два и можно спокойно определиться, а у .NET (C#) вообще 90% случаев это ASP.NET, когда с «плюсами» это :

1. Embedded
2. Game Developing
3. Desktop (MFC, Qt)
4. Low-level Dev (не Embedded даже близко как некоторые считают)
5. Серверные приложения (Хоть это и странно но я встречал такое под *nix)

— Это разные направления, по мимо того что сам С++ огромен и сложен, иногда кажется что он просто избыточен и слишком запутан да страшен, а также думается что он просто изжил своё в этом WEB-мире при том что на Windows его успешно заменяет C# в настольных приложениях и утилитах а также в Unity3D это основной язык. Иногда хочется переучится на что-нибуть иное, более перспективное и простое но я потратил 8 месяцев на его упорное изучение и хочу выбрать ПЕРСПЕКТИВНОЕ направление, WEB технологию не выбрал изначально потому что не хочу всю жизнь ковыряться в разметке HTML+JS !

Из моих выводов (судя с вакансий) Game Developing — очень не плохо набирает обороты особенно казуальные и «смартфонные» игры, а там конечно могу ошибаться, но на то и вы есть, по этому подскажите по своему опыту, что делать ? Куда податься ? Хочу на работу и немного денег на хлеб (можно без масла).

Comment: Да, 8 месяцев на C++ это много!

Comment: вот уже месяц практически с нуля изучаю игрострой под смартплатформы. Мне нравится, хотя я нубище полный.

Answer (score 6):

Работать надо в той области, которая нравится. Как-то странно как незнакомый лично человек вроде меня может подсказать вам путь в жизни. Все пути имеют свои плюсы (ыхыхы) и минусы. Могу оценить лишь перспективность направлений исходя из собственного опыта.

1. Embedded чувствует себя довольно неплохо. Много проектов, маловероятность переезда на какой-то другой язык. Возможность познакомиться с большим количеством смежных техногий. Широкий спектр задач, выбирай не хочу. Однако врменеами штука довольно скучная и рутинная. На вечеринке друзей/подруг обычно сложно впечатлить тем что ты запихнул в маелькую коробку поточный шифратор данных со скоростью шифрования 1Гб/с
2. GameDev. Вы правильно угадали тренд, действительно сейчас в наших краях популярнее всего казуальные и мобильные игры, т.н. социалочки и всё что с ними связано. Вопреки расхожему мнения на "плюсах" там в основном серверный бэкэнд (см. п. 5) и инструменты. Тут скорее всего не понадобится перемножать "руками" и считать всевозможное распространение звука в вязкой среде. Математика есть только в "классических" больших проектах для PC/консолей. ПК рынок разработки у нас как-то подистрепался, но есть ряд контор которые работают на аутсорсе для крупных западныхн разработчиков. Отечественных разработчиков с собственными проектами можно пересчитать по пальцам (одной руки).
3. Десктоп. Мало приходится сталкиваться. По-моему сейчас это мало кому нужно. Но QT и WinForms (или что там сейчас модно?) знать полезно. Однако я с трудом себе могу представить "сложность" этого пути. По-моему въехать в это дело можно за месяц, что позволяет в любой момент обратиться к этому направлению при необходимости (вот мне сейчас срочно пришлось переписать старый самодельный MFC Conrol в старой программе, не самая приятная задача, но не сложная, точно. Раньше с MFC не сталкивался никогда вообще). Можно прочитать книжку по QT и/или MFC/WinForms/Whateveryoulike чтобы блестнуть при случае эрудицией на собеседовании.
4. Низкоруровневое программирование? Что вы имеете ввиду? Драйвера? Я бы всё-таки подумал про С здесь. С трудом представляю зачем тут нужно ООП.
5. Серверные приложения. Очень богатая и плодородная тема. От рассчёта финансовых рисков при биржевых торгах до коммутаторов сотовой связи (тут конечно пополам с Embedded, но по сути то же серверное прилоежние). Описание этого раздела потянет на монографию )))

Answer (score 0):

Ваш мозг хорошо математически подкован ? Если да, то вперёд в **GameDev** !!!

Comment: Перед тем как принять это решение скачайте исходники Doom 3, найдите там файл Matrix.cpp посмотрите на гигантский метод обращения матрицы 6*6 сделанный вручную без циклов и условных переходов и 1000 раз подумайте надо ли вам это или нет.

Answer (score 0):

И математика в игрострое довольно не слабая !

Comment: Смотря что нравиться и что хочется !!!